# azure search performance issue

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I'm built an index in azure search. the index contains several fields but only 2 of the fields I marked as searchable.
the index have full words pdf files from various sizes ( the text of them of course) and its purporse to be able to use in document search.

The index is large in size - 160k documents and 7.2 gb size.

When I do a query up until 2 letters everything is working as well but when I hit complex words the performance is bad.

for example: the phrase - elasti took 59 seconds.

In my query - i use filter,scoring profile highlight

after some investigation - i can see that the highlight feature is causing the problem.

Any idea? how can increase performance - maybe split into several fields in the index or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We deployed a change that improves highlighter performance this week. Reindexing is required to enable the feature. Please feel free to contact me directly at nateko@microsoft.com if the issue persists. Thank you again for your time.

Nate

Comment: thanks. i look into it - quick question - how do you reindex? upload the document again?

Comment: You'd have to create a new index and upload the documents. BTW, what language analyzers are you using? Thanks!

Comment: @NatoKo sorry for the late response. I don't use any language analyzer for now. I will rebuild the index and see if the problem got solved. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your guess is right - search highlight is causing the issue here. When highlighting is enabled, Azure Search processes each item/text in the result set at *query time* to find text segments containing the seach hits. If each text is 4.5mb (7.2gb/160k), the process may take long. Regarding complex terms or phrases taking longer time, that would be because Azure Search stops processing the result after it finds enough number of segments. I work in Azure Search team. I will look at the code and confirm.

Comment: OK. So how do I fix that? is there a way to limit the number of phrases? I would have thought that if the search index the words he would put a point to where they are in the documents to avoid searching the entire document.  And Microsoft should put in the documentation that highlight option have performance penalty. the entire project that i currently working on is based on the highlight and i would like to have some sort of a solution to that.

Comment: We are actively looking into ways to improve search performance especially in highlighting. We will get back to the thread shortly.

Comment: @NateKo do you guys have a github repo or something to file issues, I'm having quite a lot of issues with Azure Search right now that I want to submit and follow up.

Comment: @Bart

Please use Azure forum (link below) to file issues or ask any questions. Thanks!
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/azure/en-US/home?forum=azuresearch